# Unable to access UNC path via windows service even when using same user for service

Tags: windows, azure, service, azure-active-directory

I have a windows vm and have created an Admin user, let's say - AdminUser. I have mounted an azure file share to that user to Z: drive. The share can be accessed by unc path or the drive path. I also have a c# utility that checks if path exists and it returns true when I run it. This is all good. Now when I created a windows service with that utility and with same user credential, it throws an error that the path doesn't exist.
Things to note -

- The service user or the user I used to login is a local adminstrator user and while creating the service, I had provided as "./AdminUser" to `CreateService`. Also provided password to config.
- The VM is also connected to a domain. So I have users from `default-domain\*` and `connected-domain\*`. The connected-domain linked to an azure active directory.

Is there any other type of user I need to set as log on to service?

I can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/local-user-accounts) it says the local user can't access network resources but I am wondering since I mounted the path with proper credentials, does this matter?

**Update:**
Got the same issue when using running as with the exe.

```
runas /user:USER­NAME “C:\full\path\of\Program.exe”
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to use cmdkey to store the credentials that can be used by SMB later. Launch a cmd.exe with the user that you want to use for the service using either context menu or command e.g.

```
runas /user:default-domain\domainServiceUser cmd
```

Then in the new command shell use cmdkey

```
cmdkey /add:<storagteAccountName>.file.core.windows.net\<shareName> /user:AZURE\<storageAccountName> /pass:<storageAccountKey>
```

Rerun the service and it should work.

If you want to also mount this as a persistent drive, you can use

Command Prompt

```
net use z: \\<storagteAccountName>.file.core.windows.net\<shareName> /persistent:yes
```

Powershell

```
New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\<storagteAccountName>.file.core.windows.net\<shareName>" -Persist
```

Make sure that the user is exactly the same that would be used for the windows service including the domain i.e. use default-domain\domainServiceUser or ./AdminUser for running the cmdkey.

Comment: thanks. I was missing the cmdkey, was using credential through `net use z:` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Though the user account is same, when the windows service runs as a 'user' the logon session that it gets is different than the interactive user session (which has the Z drive). Unless you programmatically load the Azure fileshare as a network drive in your code that is part of the Windows service, you won't be able to access it.

Comment: That's not the case with a VM without a domain enabled. Let' say I have an user called "xyz". So, If I logon via xyz, mount the drive and then create the service with same "xyz" as user, it can access the drive. But doing the same step in a domain connected vm, doesn't find the drive. Here "xyz" is an use of local/default domain.